# Selecting Array Elements with the Custom Columns Kubernetes CLI Output

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

How can I use the `--output=custom-columns` option for the the Kubernetes CLI (`kubectl`) to select array elements?

In other words, how can I turn this:

```shell
kubectl get services

#=>

NAME            TYPE       CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP      PORT(S)          AGE
kafka-manager   NodePort   10.3.242.200   146.148.20.235   9000:32619/TCP   0d
spark-master    NodePort   10.3.242.209   104.199.21.235   9000:32619/TCP   0d
```

into this?

```shell
kubectl get services \
--output=custom-columns=. . .

#=>

NAME            EXTERNAL-ENDPOINT     
kafka-manager   146.148.20.225:9000
spark-master    104.199.21.225:7077
```

What I have so far:

```shell
kubectl get services \
--output=custom-columns='NAME:.metadata.name,IP:.spec.clusterIP,PORT:.spec.ports'

#=>

NAME            IP             PORT
kafka-manager   10.3.242.200   [map[nodePort:32619 port:9000 protocol:TCP targetPort:9000]]
spark-master    10.3.242.209   [map[nodePort:30588 port:7077 protocol:TCP targetPort:7077]]
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

**TLDR**

For an element that is in a list use `*` in square brackets.

So your query should look like this:

```shell
kubectl get service \
-n kube-system \
-o=custom-columns='NAME:.metadata.name,IP:.spec.clusterIP,PORT:.spec.ports[*].targetPort'

#=>

NAME                   IP           PORT
kube-dns               10.0.0.10    53,53
kubernetes-dashboard   10.0.0.250   9090
```

Notice the `*` in `PORT:.spec.ports[*].targetPort`.

**Details:**

So `kubectl` is expecting a `json-path-expr` after `header`. The error I got when playing with expressions was following:

```shell
expected <header>:<json-path-expr>
```

To iterate over all elements in a list instead of putting an index just use `*`.

Various other json-path expressions can be found [here](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath).

Comment: This works with bash, with zsh I get `zsh: no matches found: -o=custom-columns=NAME:.metadata.name,IP:.spec.clusterIP,PORT:.spec.ports[*].targetPort`. Any ideas?

Comment: Got it, you need to quote your custom-columns expression, so this works: `kubectl get service -n kube-system  -o=custom-columns="NAME:.metadata.name,IP:.spec.clusterIP,PORT:.spec.ports[*].targetPort"`

Answer (score 6):

If you want to search in a map using custom columns, you can use

```
[?(@.Key=="Value"]
```

An important thing if you want to use it, is that the query in the custom-columns must be insider `[']` character.

For example, the following query fails:

```
kubectl get nodes -o=custom-columns=NAME:.metadata.name,CPU:.status.capacity.cpu,MEM:.status.capacity.memory,IP:.status.addresses[?(@.type=="InternalIP")].address
```

> bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

But if we execute the same query using `[']` character it works:

```
kubectl get nodes -o=custom-columns='NAME:.metadata.name,ROLE:TOBEDEFINED,CPU:.status.capacity.cpu,MEM:.status.capacity.memory,IP:.status.addresses[?(@.type=="InternalIP")].address'
```

```
NAME        CPU   MEM   IP
name-node   8     8     10.10.10.10
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `*` for understanding the data in the JSON. For example:

```shell
kubectl get svc gdpr -o custom-columns='svc:*'
```

As for me, the `get` command was perfect (due external IP info.) and looks like:

```shell
kubectl get svc -o custom-columns='SVC:.metadata.name,IP:.metadata.annotations.domainName,PORT:.spec.ports[*].targetPort'

#=>

SVC      IP          PORT
event    site1.com   9000 
gdpr     site2.com   3333,8080
svcInt   none        80
ui       site6.com   80,6123,6124,6125,8081
```

P.S. About list external IP and hosts:

```shell
kubectl get nodes -o jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{.metadata.name} {.status.addresses[?(@.type=="ExternalIP")].address}{"\n"}'

#=>

ip-10-10-40-13.xxxxx.internal xx.xx.xx.175
ip-10-10-40-15.xxxxx.internal xx.xx.xx.236
ip-10-10-40-18.xxxxx.internal xx.xx.xx.207
```

```shell
kubectl get nodes -o jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{.status.addresses[?(@.type=="ExternalIP")].address}{"\n"}'

#=>

xx.xx.xx.175
xx.xx.xx.236
xx.xx.xx.207
```

Comment: Is it possible to limit the output based column value on using "custom-columns" like "type=="ExternalIP"" in "jsonpath".

Comment: yes. by array option like [] if you know the number order or with grep, like:
kubectl get nodes -o jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{.status.addresses[?(@.type=="ExternalIP")].address}{"\n"}' |grep 175 |cut -d\. -f4
will only 175

for columns better to use "-o=custom-column"

p.s. describe pls more detail you input and wanted output data

Comment: I want to be in single kubectl command. I tried command "kubectl  get nodes --no-headers -o=custom-columns=.:status.addresses[?(@type)] --selector "glusterfs=storage-host"", but getting and map like "map[address:10.70.xx.xx type:InternalIP],map[address:xx.xx.com type:Hostname]
map[address:10.70.xx.xx type:InternalIP],map[address:xx.xx.com type:Hostname]
map[type:InternalIP address:10.70.xx.xx],map[address:xx.xx.com type:Hostname]
" and I need output like "10.70.xx.xx xx.xx.com
10.70.xx.xx xx.xx.com
10.70.xx.xx xx.xx.com" based on type provided.

Comment: I tried command "kubectl get nodes --no-headers -o=custom-columns=.:status.addresses[?(@.type==InternalIP)] --selector "glusterfs=storage-host"
error: unrecognized identifier InternalIP" but get an error "get nodes --no-headers -o=custom-columns=.:status.addresses[?(@.type==InternalIP)] --selector "glusterfs=storage-host"
error: unrecognized identifier InternalIP"

Answer (score 1):

Would that work for you?

```
kubectl get service -o=custom-columns=NAME:.metadata.name,IP:.spec.clusterIP,PORT:.spec.ports[0].targetPort
```

Comment: That's how it came back to me like this:
kubectl get service -o=custom-columns=NAME:.metadata.name,IP:.spec.clusterIP,PORT:..spec..targetPort

NAME         IP               PORT
kubernetes   10.96.0.1        443
nginx        10.100.136.114   80
node         10.100.162.143   2368

Is that what you wanted?

Comment: Okay, nice, so use an additional dot. How ever still don't know how to just use the x-th port listed. And I would love to concat columns.

Comment: Unfortunately I was blocked because of the response, so if you could vote for me I would appreciate it, thank you!